# Printing different elements of a polymorphic array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, overriding

For this problem, I was given the following hierarchy: a base class Person, a subclass Employee, and subclasses  Staff and Supervisor. I needed to apply method overriding in classes Employee, Staff, and Supervisor. and the main method of the driver class needs to create several objects of Staff and Supervisor, and display their names and monthly pay.

I built a polymorphic array in the driver class, but I can't figure out how to construct the for loop to display each element of the array next to the overridden method return values.  I kept the base and sub classes exceedingly simple:

```
public class Person {


void Salary(){
System.out.println("All positions are salaried");

}
}
public class Employee extends Person {

void Salary(){
    System.out.println("Salaries vary between staff and supervisors");
}

}
public class Staff extends Employee {

public Staff(String string) {

}

void Salary() {
    System.out.println("A regular staff employee makes 3500.00 monthly");
}


}
public class Supervisor extends Employee {


public Supervisor(String string) {
}

void Salary(){
    System.out.println("Supervisors make approximately 9800.00 monthly");
}
}
```

Here is the driver class, where I'm having the issue:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HRRoster {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    Person roster[] = new Person[6];  
    roster[0] = new Supervisor("James Martin");
    roster[1] = new Supervisor("William Smith");
    roster[2] = new Supervisor("Jennifer Shipman");
    roster[3] = new Staff("Brian Williams");
    roster[4] = new Staff("Carrie James");
    roster[5] = new Staff("Samantha Powers");



            for (int i=0; i < roster.length; i++){
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(roster));
                roster[i].Salary();
            }
    }

}
```

Right now, its output is all of the elements in the array plus the overridden method, each on its own line.  I know I'm missing something absurdly elementary/simple in my for loop, but I'm not sure exactly how to make it work from here.  Basically I want to list each element of the array followed by an execution of the overridden method, each on its own line.

Comment: You might want to use `println` for a new line output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you expecting below behaviour

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

class Person {
    String name;
    void Salary() {
        System.out.println("All positions are salaried");

    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {

    void Salary() {
        System.out.println("Salaries vary between staff and supervisors");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

}

class Staff extends Employee {

    public Staff(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void Salary() {
        System.out.println("A regular staff employee makes 3500.00 monthly");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }


}

class Supervisor extends Employee {

    public Supervisor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void Salary() {
        System.out.println("Supervisors make approximately 9800.00 monthly");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class HRRoster {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person roster[] = new Person[6];
        roster[0] = new Supervisor("James Martin");
        roster[1] = new Supervisor("William Smith");
        roster[2] = new Supervisor("Jennifer Shipman");
        roster[3] = new Staff("Brian Williams");
        roster[4] = new Staff("Carrie James");
        roster[5] = new Staff("Samantha Powers");

        for (int i = 0; i < roster.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(roster[i].toString() + "\t");
            roster[i].Salary();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Very close; I'm looking for something to actually display the names/elements of the roster next to how much they make... eg:  James Martin  Supervisors make approximately 9800.00 monthly.

Comment: updated the answer, I strongly recommend you to go through basics. and accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Duh.  KNEW I was missing something simple.  Also know I'm still a bit rusty; just getting back into this after a year break and a crappy teacher.